# Getting first row with null

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with the columns

```
    drop TABLE "public"."opportunities";
CREATE TABLE "public"."opportunities" ( 
     "itemcode"     VARCHAR COLLATE "default", 
     "creationtime" TIMESTAMPTZ(6) NOT NULL, 
     "finishtime"   TIMESTAMPTZ(6), 
     "ordertag"     INT8, 
     "trackingblob" VARCHAR
); 
insert into opportunities VALUES ('1', now(), null, NULL, 'blob1');
insert into opportunities VALUES ('1', now(), null, 2, 'blob2');
insert into opportunities VALUES ('1', now(), null, null, 'blob3');
insert into opportunities VALUES ('2', now(), null, NULL, 'blob1a');
insert into opportunities VALUES ('2', now(), null, 2, 'blob2a');
insert into opportunities VALUES ('2', now(), null, null, 'blob3a');
```

The expected result would be the rows with blob1 and blob1a.

I would like to get for every orderTag, the tracking blob of the previous entry with OrderTag as null - there might be rows after the timestamp which should be ignored as well.
Is this possible in a single SQL or do I need to write a program with two steps?.

Comment: Can you add some sample data, and the expected result (with that sample data)?

Comment: I have added a sample as requested.

Comment: What if blob3 had an OrderTag - should blob2 be returned, or just blob1?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from opportunities op1
where (select ordertag from opportunities op2
       where op2.creationtime =
           (select min(creationtime) from opportunities op3
            where op3.creationtime > op1.creationtime)) is not null
```

I.e. return a row of the next row (creationtime-wise) has an ordertag which is not null.

Comment: I get no rows back when running together with the sql statement from above - I also miss the grouping by order tag.

Comment: When I tested it returned the expected rows. Maybe timing differences? Slow down the INSERT's and see if it makes any difference?